# jQuery - How to dynamically add a validation rule

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add a validation rule to some dynamic controls:

```
$("input[id*=Hours]").rules("add", "required");
```

However this line gives me the following error:

**$.data(element.form, "validator") is null**

Defining rules the static way with the validate function works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You need to call [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) before you can add rules this way, like this:

```
$("#myForm").validate(); //sets up the validator
$("input[id*=Hours]").rules("add", "required");
```

The [`.validate()` documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Plugin_methods) is a good guide, here's the blurb about [`.rules("add", option)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules):

> Adds the specified rules and returns all rules for the first matched element. Requires that the parent form is validated, that is, `$("form").validate()` is called first.

Comment: Thanks, calling validate first solved that error. However it's only validating the first input with an id like Hours instead of validating all of them, any idea why?

Comment: Each ID is to be considered a unique element in the DOM -- maybe you want to use a class here?

Comment: jquery validate work with the name attribute of the input not the Id, maybe that is your problem Justin

Comment: For some reason, even with a broad class based selector, jQuery Validator only ever seems to select the first element of that type. I spent a long time wondering what was going on, but eventually gave up and did something similar to what @Rick has done in a different answer. That is, something like `$(".requiredGroup").each(function () {
      $(this).rules('add', 'required');
  });`

Comment: this does not seem to work? fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/z1haze/e8z6wv3g/24/

Comment: @StephenHendricks you have two elements with the same name in the form, that's why your jsfiddle doesn't work, check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/ADn06/e8z6wv3g/38/

Answer (score 43):

To validate all dynamically generated elements could add a special class to each of these elements and use each() function, something like

```
$("#DivIdContainer .classToValidate").each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

Comment: what about messages? here is example from documentation https://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/#example:-adds-minlength:-2-to-an-element-which-is-already-required

Answer (score 4):

As well as making sure that you have first called `$("#myForm").validate();`, make sure that your dynamic control has been added to the DOM before adding the validation rules.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules) says:

> Adds the specified rules and returns
> all rules for the first matched
> element. Requires that the parent form
> is validated, that is,

```
> $("form").validate() is called first.
```

Did you do that? The error message kind of indicates that you didn't.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want jquery validate to auto pick validations on dynamically added items, you can simply remove and add validation on the whole form like below

```
//remove validations on entire form
$("#yourFormId")
    .removeData("validator")
    .removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

//Simply add it again
$.validator
    .unobtrusive
    .parse("#yourFormId");
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much, this solved one of my biggest problems, omg :s, before knowing this, I would only call the parse() method, and it wouldn't fully cover the newly added inputs, but by removing it first, it now validates all of them, thank you so much.