# adding validation rule(s) to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate elements in a form that is created dynammically. However, the code for adding rules (`'$("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });'`) in the code below does not seem to work (e.g., no response).

What am I doing wrong? (for this adding-rule code I used the page view-source:http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/jqueryvalidation/testadd.cfm as an example, which does work. Also added .validate() at the start of the document.ready function, e.g. before adding the rule as suggested in [jQuery - How to dynamically add a validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule) , but that does not work either...)

Please your suggestions...

Code (with simplified form):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods-v2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
            var addForm = $("#add-form");
            var index = 0;

            $("#myForm").validate();

            var getForm = function(index, action) { //returns set of form fields as a string
            return $('\
                <table>\
                <tr>\
                <td> Name </td> <td> Email </td> <td> Phone </td>\
                </tr>\
                <tr>\
                <td> <input id="name' + index + '" name="name' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="email' + index + '" name="email' + index + '" /></td>\
                <td><input id="phone' + index + '" name="phone' + index + '" /></td>\
                <input type="submit" value="Save">\
                </tr>\
                </table>\
                <a href="#" class="remove">remove form</a>\
                ');
            }//getForm()

            addForm.on("click", function() {
                var form = getForm(++index)
                form.find(".remove").on("click", function() {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                }); //form.find()
                $("#wrapper").append(form);
                $("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });
            }); //addForm.on()


            $("#myForm").validate({
     //console.log("validate");

                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
           error.insertAfter(element);
                   },
                rules: {
                        email: {
            required: true

        }
                } //rules

    }); //validate()

        }); //$(document).ready
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="" method="post" autocomplete="on">
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <a href="#" id="add-form">add form</a>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule

Comment: correct, I referred to that link as well and indicated that putting .validate() before adding the rule does not seem to work; I added '$("#myForm").validate();' just before the line '$("#email"+index).rules("add", { required:true,email:true });' and also tried by putting the validate line at the start of the documenten ready function. I could also ask: where precisely in the code to put the $("#myForm").validate() line (if that would be the error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `$("#myForm").validate()` twice.  Once without options and subsequently with options.  You can only call it *once* (initialization) and all subsequent calls are ignored.

So simply remove the second one and place all the options into the first one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
        var addForm = $("#add-form");
        var index = 0;

        $("#myForm").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            rules: {
                email: { // <-- does this input exist on DOM ready?
                    required: true
                }
            } //rules
         }); //validate()

        ....
```

However, the `rules` declaration would be invalid if the `input` with `name="email"` does not exist yet.  Since it seems like your `form` is starting out with zero `input` elements, you would need to remove the `rules` declaration...

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    }
}); //validate()
```

Comment: thnx (!) that works. (though I still dont understand why the mentioned example http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/demos/jqueryvalidation/testadd.cfm does work as that code calls validate() after adding the rule...)

Comment: @user2543182, in your linked example, `.validate()` is called after the `click` handler function, **not** after "adding the rule".  Remember that the rule is added only when you click the button, which is long after `.validate()` is fired on DOM ready.  You should be able to do the same, however, you may also have been dealing with other issues simultaneously.

Comment: @user2543182, it's important to keep straight what gets called when the page loads (`.validate()` is the initialization) versus what gets called when events occur.  The `.validate()` method is never called again after the page loads.