# How to use required inside addMethod in jQuery Validate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am trying to use jQuery Validate plugin addMethod for validating multiple fields of similar validation conditions. Those fields are required depending on another dropdown selection.
How can I use required:true property inside an addMethod?

All I can think of is JS code to check if the field is empty. But I want a cleaner way.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<td>
<input type="text" name="examname1" id="en1" maxlength="8" size="8" disabled="disabled" onkeypress="return isAlphaKey(event)" />
</td>
```

jQuery :

```
//common validation method for education details in first row
jQuery.validator.addMethod ("prox_education1", function (value, element) {
        if ($("#education").val() >= 1)
        {
            ?????
        }
}, "This field is required");
```

How do I make the field required if the condition is true?

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod (...) {
if (condition)
{
   make this element required
}
else
{
   ignore
}
"Error: This field is required and you left it blank"
```

Comment: please share your code and explain what you need

Comment: inside the plugin's addMethod you can use `this.optional(element)` to check whether an element is required or not

Comment: I don't want to check if the element is required. I want to make it required if the condition is true.

Comment: Sounds like the following may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule

Comment: The example you gave uses id for adding rules. I want to add the rules for multiple fields.
Please see the code and suggest what can be used in place of ????.

Comment: I could make the field required by using
`$(element).rules ("add", {
required: true,
});`
But now the error is not going away even when the field is not blank.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a field required based on a condition, you can pass a function as the required rule value and it can return true/false like

```
rules: {
    somefield: {
        required: function () {
            return $('#f1').is(':checked');
        }
    }
},
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ugsmctu2/)

---

Another option is to use the [rules api](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) like

```
//add
$('#f2').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
//remove
$('#f2').rules('remove', 'required');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ugsmctu2/2/)

Comment: This will work for one field. But I want to make **multiple** fields required based on the **same** condition. That's why I'm using addMethod. I hope I'm explaining it correctly.

Comment: @user1543784 then create a demo using the attached fiddles to demonstrate your problem