# Dynamic fields are not becoming required in jquery validation

Tags: jquery, validation, each

[image]Here i want to make all dynamic fields required that are calling from an ajax page so in order to make all fields required i wrote the code like this

```
<script src="http://demo.expertphp.in/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#toUploadButton').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('input.product_price').each(function() {
  $(this).rules("add", 
      {
          required:true,
          messages: {
              required: "Name is required",
          }
      });
  });
  e.preventDefault();
 $("#add_product").validate();
});
</script>
```

My ajax view file looks like this

```
<tr class="tr_clone_product ajax_result">
  <td style="width:200px;"><input class="product_price" type="text" name="product_price[]" id="product_price" style="width:200px;"></td>  
</tr>
```

My main view file is here

```
<form method="POST" name="add_product" id="add_product" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('/admin/products/store') }}">
@csrf

<div class="col-12">
    <table class="table table-bordered all_products">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="product_list">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="offset-4 col-8">
    <button name="toUploadButton" type="button"  id="toUploadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here in the place of class `product_list` the ajax page is loading and i want to make all the fields inside the ajax page to be required but the problem is only the first row is becoming required

Comment: you should attach validation rule after input dynamically loaded i.e. inside your ajax call from where you are adding product price inputs

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar i just added the same way as you told but its not working

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with code snippet or jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: `$('input.product_price')` is *not* a "live" query - it gets those inputs that exist at the time the code runs.  If you add controls later, this won't be applied.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery - How to dynamically add a validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule)

Comment: Apparently you need call .validate() before adding the rule, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3034059/2181514

Comment: *only the first row* - I'm not sure about jquery,validate, but quite often these things require a *unique* id on each control (or possibly *no id*) - your ajax returns `<input class="product_price" type="text" id="product_price"` - so all your inputs have the same ID.  This might explain why only the first one is being validated.

Comment: @freedomn-m here am not validating the field based on id

Comment: Didn't say you were, I said jquery.validate *might* be - but worth ruling out and fixing anyway because IDs must be unique within a DOM document.  It also matches the "first row" only observation.