# How to require input by select option from dropdown in ASP.NET Core

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core

I want the desired input to be required when I select a specific option from the dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" required name="[@i].Ansere" asp-for="@Model.ToList()[i].Ansere">
     <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
     <option value="بله">بله</option>
     <option value="خیر">خیر</option>
     <option value="اقدام شد">اقدام شد</option>
     <option value="عدم نیاز">عدم نیاز</option>
     <option value="ابلاغ">ابلاغ</option>
</select>

<td colspan="3"><input class="form-control text-sm"  placeholder="شرح مورد ارزیابی ..." name="[@i].Discreption" autocomplete="off"/></td>
```

Comment: You can add or remove "rule" dynamically. Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033910/jquery-how-to-dynamically-add-a-validation-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update2:**

Do you mean to add `required` attribute to input only when `Ansere2` is selected? You can add a judgment condition:

```
function test(newValue)
{
    var Ansere = newValue.value;
    if (Ansere == "Ansere2")
    {
        var selectName = newValue.name;
        var inputName = selectName.replace("Ansere", "Discreption");
        var input = $("input[name="+"'"+inputName+"'"+"]");
                
        $(input).prop('required',true);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to use the name of `input`, you can refer to my code below:

```
@for(var i = 0; i  < 5; i++)
{
        <select class="form-control" required name="[@i].Ansere" asp-for="@Model[@i].Ansere" onchange="test(this)">
            <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="Ansere1">Ansere1</option>
            <option value="Ansere2">Ansere2</option>
            <option value="Ansere3">Ansere3</option>
            <option value="Ansere4">Ansere4</option>
            <option value="Ansere5">Ansere5</option>
        </select>

        <td colspan="3"><input class="form-control text-sm"  placeholder="شرح مورد ارزیابی ..." name="[@i].Discreption" autocomplete="off"/></td>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function test(newValue)
        {
            var Ansere = newValue.value;
            var selectName = newValue.name;
            var inputName = selectName.replace("Ansere", "Discreption");
            var input = $("input[name="+"'"+inputName+"'"+"]");
            $(input).prop('required',true);
        }
    </script>
}
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

If you have multiple selects without id to distinguish, you can refer to my code below.

I wrap `select` and `input` in a `div`, then monitor the change of `select`:

```
@model List<TestApp.Models.MyModel>

@for(var i = 0; i  < 5; i++)
{
    <div>
        <select class="form-control" required name="[@i].Ansere" asp-for="@Model[@i].Ansere" onchange="test(this)">
            <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="Ansere1">Ansere1</option>
            <option value="Ansere2">Ansere2</option>
            <option value="Ansere3">Ansere3</option>
            <option value="Ansere4">Ansere4</option>
            <option value="Ansere5">Ansere5</option>
        </select>

        <td colspan="3"><input class="form-control text-sm"  placeholder="شرح مورد ارزیابی ..." name="[@i].Discreption" autocomplete="off"/></td>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function test(newValue)
        {
            var Ansere = newValue.value;
            var input = newValue.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
            $(input).prop('required',true);
        }
    </script>
}
```

TestResult:
[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Please post the image of the result of the code, thank you

Comment: My friend, I tried this, but it didn't work. Have you test this?

Comment: What should I put instead newValue?

Comment: And what does this mean ? getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

Comment: Hi @sadegh, you can see I added `onchange` event to select, and take `this` as a parameter. The `newValue` parameter in the js code is the `select` element after your selection. `newValue.parentElement` is the `div` element on the outer layer of `select`, `getElementsByTagName('input')[0]` is the `input` element in the `div`.

Comment: When you have multiple select and corresponding input, you can monitor the changed select and perform operations on the corresponding input.

Comment: I have several inputs and I don't want to use a div. Please change this code and test it. Thank you very much.getElementsByTagName('input')[0] For example, take the name Inputs

Comment: My friend this code required all inputs But I want only the option that value  <option value="Ansere2">Ansere2</option> If selected, the corresponding input will be required

Comment: Hi @sadegh, please check my updated answer again. Is this what you want?